# Не могу убрать класс добавленный с помощью .append после hover

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Задача состоит в появлении вот такого подчеркивания при наведении на элемент навигации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил создать для этого следующий элемент:

```css
.underline {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 4px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: red;/*color for test
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class='underline'>
</div>
```

и использовал следующий код jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$(".main-nav_item").hover(function() {
    $(this).append($('.underline'));
  });

// или же 
  
$(".main-nav_item").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).append($('.underline'));
  });
    $(".main-nav_item").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.underline').removeClass();
  });

});
```

Учитывая то, что элементы приведенные на картинке выше имеют класс `.main-nav_item` все должно было работать корректно, но я столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда уводишь курсор с ссылки не на другую ссылку, а на какой-то другой элемент - эффект подчеркивания все равно остается. В случае если уводить на другую ссылку - все работает корректно.

Как видите, применил 2 варианта jQuery, но не один не подошел. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема.  Благодарю.

Comment: можно было бы все это сделать псевдо селекторами :before && :after и без использования jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот CSS:

```
    li p {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
li p:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
li p:hover:before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  background: #000;
}
```

Вот HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Pizza</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Думаю вообщем будет не сложно разобраться и jquery не нужно применять:
http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/KgQjQN  должно быть видно

Comment: Благодарю, буду разбираться)

Comment: Не за что)
Почитай за псевдо-селекторы без них очень худо)

Answer (score 2):

Можно обойтись селекторами [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), и [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)/[::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

```css
.main-nav_item:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.main-nav_item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item1
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item2
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item3
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item4
</div>
```

Проблема кода в вопросе в том, что метод `hover` в таком виде вызывается дважды: один раз при наведении, один раз при снятии, при этом каждый раз добавляется элемент *underline*

```
$(".main-nav_item").hover(function() {
  $(this).append($('.underline'));
});
```

Вместо этого можно воспользоваться тем, что данная функция может принимать отдельные обработчики на наведение и снятие и указать в одном добавление, в другом снятие:

```js
$(".main-nav_item").hover(function() {
  $(this).append($('<div>').addClass('underline'));
}, function() {
  $('.underline', this).remove();
});
```

```css
.underline {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
.main-nav_item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item1
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item2
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item3
</div>
<div class='main-nav_item'>
  item4
</div>
```

В случае с mouseenter/mouseleave аналогично, так как [.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) является краткой записью для этих методов

Comment: Благодарю, все работает, ошибку понял.

Answer (score 1):

Если уже очень хочется именно в таком виде сделать, то можно как-то так:

```js
$(".main-nav_item").hover(function() {
  
    $(this).append($('.underline'));
  
}, function(){
  
    $('.underline').appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
.underline {
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 4px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 1000;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000;
}
  
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-1</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-2</a></li>
</ul>
  
<div class="underline"></div>
```

**P.S**:

```
.hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

---

**Правильнее** все же будет **добавлять\удалять класс**:

```js
$(".main-nav_item").hover(function() {
  
    $(this).addClass('underline');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('underline');
});
```

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
}

.underline:after {
  content: '';
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 4px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 1000;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000;
}
  
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-1</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

А еще **лучше** использовать для этих целей **CSS**!!! :

```css
.main-nav_item {
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav_item:hover:after {
  content: '';
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 4px;
 height: 1px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 1000;
}


/* Стили для наглядности */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #000;
}
  
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-1</a></li>
  <li class="main-nav_item"><a href="#">item-2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ!